# Diagonalizable and finding Complex Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the matrix

$\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}$
**over the complex numbers**.

Explain/show that it is Diagonalizable and find a complex matrix $\gamma$ and a diagonal matrix $\delta$ such that $\gamma ^{-1} \beta \gamma=\delta$

**Effort so far**

I have shown that it is indeed not possible over the real numbers and I know that
to diagonalize a matrix $A$

Find the eigenvalues of $A$ using the characteristic polynomial.

For each eigenvalue $λ$ of $A$ , compute a basis $B λ$ for the $λ$-eigenspace.

If there are fewer than $n$ total vectors in all of the eigenspace bases $B λ$ , then the matrix is not diagonalizable. I am having trouble with showing this over the complex numbers and to find the matrices $\gamma , \delta$

Comment: the way you wrote it, the columns of $\gamma$ are eigenvectors.

Comment: this matrix has real spectrum https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B7%2C3%2C4%7D%2C%7B-2%2C-1%2C2%7D%2C%7B6%2C2%2C-3%7D%7D

Comment: @janmarqz No, it as not. The matrix that you have given to WolframAlpha is not $\beta$.

Comment: @WillJagy what do you mean exactly?

Comment: oops! ok... here is the correction https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B7%2C3%2C-4%7D%2C%7B-2%2C-1%2C2%7D%2C%7B6%2C2%2C-3%7D%7D

Comment: @janmarqz how would I argue that the matrix is indeed diagonalizable

Comment: @bymathformath: this is because has three different eigenvalues and then three different eigenvectors giving the matrix that allows the diagonalization as indicated by the WolframAlpha result

Comment: @janmarqz I have the quote that "A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalues." What would these values be in my case and how would I read them

Comment: the zeroes of the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? I have got the characteristic polynomial but the zeros are  what? The algebraic or geometric?

Comment: Here below, in the answer of José Carlos Santos you can see the characteristic polynomial of your matrix which can be factorized as he told, the problem that I see there is that the diagonalization that he gave is not the same as wolframAlpha calculated. The zeroes are the roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $\beta$ is $-\lambda^3+3\lambda^2-\lambda+3=(3-\lambda)(\lambda^2+1)$, whose roots are $3$, $i$, and $-i$. If you search for eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues, you will see that, for instance:

- $(1-i,2i,2)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$;
- $(1+i,-2i,2)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-i$;
- $(1,0,1)$ is an eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$.

So, if you take$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1-i&1+i&1\\2i&-2i&0\\2&2&1\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $M$ are the eigenvectors that I got) then$$M^{-1}\beta M=\begin{bmatrix}i&0&0\\0&-i&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I did not find these eigenvectors for the different eigenvalues. I found $i$ to give the vector $(1/2 + i/2, -i, 1)$ and $-i$ to give the vector $(1/2 - i/2, i, 1)$. And how would I argue for diagonalizeability?

Comment: @bymathformath So what? That changes nothing. For each eigenvalue, there are infinitely many eigenvectors.

Comment: @bymathformath Using other eigenvectors, you get another matrix $M$. But the diagonal matrix that you get at the end is always the same.

Comment: Okay I see. why is that the case that this always works i.e any family of eigenvectors gives the same diagonal matrix in the end?

Comment: Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$. Then $M.e_k$ is the $k$-th eigenvalue $v_k$. Then $\beta.v_k$ is $v_k$ times the $k$-th eigenvalue. Finally $M^{-1}$ times this is the $k$-th eigenvalue time $e_k$. So, this will give you the diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are the eigenvalues.

Comment: and why is such a matrix $M$ diagonalizable

Comment: The same argument from my previous argument shows that if a matrix has a basis of eigenvalues then it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Ohhh I see now - when you say $M$ (dot) $e_k$ do you mean index or multiplied?

Comment: I mean the product of $M$ times the vector $e_k$.

Comment: But wouldn't you have to argue for $\beta$ using "A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalues."

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: the entry $(M^{-1}\beta M)_{33}$ should be $3$.

Comment: @janmarqz I've edited my answer . Thank you.

Comment: @bymathformath Did I answer your original question or not? I ask this because you keep asking questions which are independent from your question.